# Find character in string then insert character before that character

Tags: c

I am studying about string in C and I have this question . I've had a look at some question in stackoverflow but I cant find the same Question,if there is pls give me the link :D

For exp,I have a string `"D://test.txt"`

Now I want to convert it to `"D://test1.txt"`

I know that I have to find `.` in the string,then put the number befor it,but I dont know how to do it. Pls help me out :(

Comment: have you tried anything yet? hint: there's no "insert" in arrays in C, you need to do some shifting

Comment: To be very very safe, you may want to allocate some memory for the new string and copy the old string there -- doing any modification as you copy or after the copy.

Comment: What I mean is I've just find a way to do it,but I know little about C so I can make it into C language.
Is there a function that find character in string,and a function to insert character in string with given position ?

Comment: I think I would tackle this by looking at string tokenising - using `strtok()` and perhaps string copying - see `strcpy()` and possible better `strncpy()`. Also, see [examples here](http://www.teach-me-c.com/blog/breaking-string-pieces](). Herb Schildt's _"C The Complete Reference_ should be your bible after you've learnt the basics.

Comment: @wmorrison365: `strncpy()` is NOT a better `strcpy()`, it is not even a *string* function despite its name. `strncpy()` is a function desinged to work with fixed-length sequence of characters which may even not have a `'\0'`.

Comment: @DucAnh - that's what I meant, there is no function for inserting a character into a string; but there are functions to finding occurrences of a character. Are you considering paths like: `"D://test.txt.bak"` (meaning you want to find the *first* occurrence vs *every* occurrence?)

Comment: Hi @pmg, I was hinting that it may be worth copying only a portion of the original string using `strncpy`. The OP may want to investigate this way of doing it. Or, as I also suggested, `strcpy` could be used with the tokeniser. Then they may wish to do array shifting as also suggested. The OP is just wanting to learn more about C so here's some suggestions to consider for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strchr()` (or `strrchr()`) to find the dot. Both functions have their prototype in `<string.h>`.

There is no ready-made function for inserting a character in the middle of a string. You have to write your own.